Android studio java application ChatActivity Edittext hide behind keyboard
Please help me in Android studio java application i want to create a chat activity like whatsapp but the problem is if user click or edittext edittext can't adjust itself and hide behind the keyboard
i try all thing like fitssystemwindows=true but it create some white space in the top of layout and resize in manifest do nothing please help me

Adjust windowSoftInputMode in Manifest:
Ensure that your activity's windowSoftInputMode is set correctly in the AndroidManifest.xml. This helps in handling the layout adjustments when the keyboard appears.
AndroidManifest.xml:
<activity
    android:name=".ChatActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>


activity_chat.xml:
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/input_layout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Type a message" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
